Inferring Schema from Blob JSON Data in Spark SQL Query for Oracle Database
I have a JSON stored as a blob in an Oracle database. I need to read it with Spark, along with other fields from the table, using a Spark SQL query like:
SELECT id, request_timestamp, response FROM my_table

Where the 'response' field is stored as a blob and contains JSON data. My requirement is to perform only Spark SQL queries without introducing additional logic, as I'm using a framework that exposes APIs for reading data, restricting the addition of custom logic.
When directly querying the data, the 'response' field is returned as binary, which prevents me from accessing its schema for SQL queries. For instance, within the 'response' field, there's a nested field called 'user_data' which is an array, and I need to perform an explode operation using lateral views on that field.
Since I need to execute a Spark SQL query first and then perform subsequent Spark SQL queries with lateral views on the 'response' field, I can't proceed without inferring the schema from the JSON. I've tried using from_json, but it requires a predefined schema, which I don't have upfront; I need to infer it from the JSON.
How can I achieve this? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Are you asking how to convert string data represented in a binary format to a string?

not to a string. I want the same result as the spark.read.json(filePath) operation, which returns, given a json, the struct with the correct schema.
So something like.
root
|-- QUOTEID: decimal(19,0) (nullable = true)
|-- timestampDate: date (nullable = true)
|-- response: struct (nullable = true)
| | |-- user_data: struct (nullable = true)
| | | |-- user_id: integer (nullable = true)
| | | |-- user_name: string (nullable = true)
| | | |-- user_surname: string (nullable = true)

If you want to use native Oracle SQL commands to process or analyze JSON, you should probably not store it in binary format. A CLOB field would better suit your purpose than a BLOB. Also, the native support for JSON will vary widely depending on the version of Oracle DB. What version are you using?

19c. I tried to use TO_CLOB(response) command, but I do not have the struct, but a string. So I need some transformation, not necessarily Oracle Sql native, but also Spark Sql.
